# Is there any significant difference between List.Last() and List.Last<T>()?

Tags: c#, linq, generics

Given a list of rectangles,

```
var myList = new List<Rectangle>();
```

I cannot add anything but Rectangles to this list, so what factors would make me prefer

```
Rectangle lastRect = myList.Last<Rectangle>();
```

over simply

```
Rectangle lastRect = myList.Last();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are exactly the same.
The thing is, the compiler uses type inference to understand what the type is, if possible.
It sees you're using a generic function on a generic type, and tries to match between them. And it works.

Short answer: These are the same, but the compiler adds the `<Rectangle>` for you, using type inference.

Answer (score 1):

To support Rubys's answer, the compiler infers the type when you call the Last method without a type parameter.

The final IL that gets generated is exactly the same - I just checked.